# Populating rows for missing sequential phases in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Original_data::

| ID | Phase | Phase Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Found | 1 |
| 12 | 'Round 1' | 2 |
| 12 | 'Round 2' | 3 |
| 12 | Check | 4 |
| 12 | Check | 4 |
| 12 | Check Done | 6 |
| 12 | Check Done | 6 |
| 12 | Wanted | 7 |

In my Original_data above, I want to add rows for the sequential phase_order before a given phase if it is not there already. So, if we look at the phase: 'Check Done' it appears twice in the original data thus the phases before 'Check Done' must appear at least twice. So at least twice for phase 'Check', at least twice for phase 'Round 2', at least twice for 'Round 1' and at least twice for 'Found'.

My final_table should look like this:

| ID | Phase | Phase Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Found | 1 |
| 12 | Found | 1 |
| 12 | Round 1 | 2 |
| 12 | Round 1 | 2 |
| 12 | Round 2 | 3 |
| 12 | Round 2 | 3 |
| 12 | Check | 4 |
| 12 | Check | 4 |
| 12 | Check Done | 6 |
| 12 | Check Done | 6 |
| 12 | Wanted | 7 |

There can be instances where you have a phase that lets say is phase_order:2 and it appears 3 times. Then also have phase_order:3 that appears 2 times.

as:

| ID | Phase Order |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 3 |

Since phase_order:3 is higher than phase_order:2 in the progression order then there needs to be at least at least 2 rows for phase_order:2 and at least 3 rows for phase_order:1 since there is minimum two rows for phase_order:3 and a minimum of three rows for phase_order:2.

Final data in this scenario:

| ID | Phase Order |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 100 | 3 |
| 100 | 3 |

Another scenario would be say you have three rows of phase_order:3 in the original data, and only one row for phase_order:1 and one row for phase_order:2.

As:

| ID | Phase Order |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 111 | 3 |

Then the final data set should be: 3 rows for phase_order:1 and 3 rows for phase_order:2 and three rows for phase_order:3.

Looking like:

| ID | Phase Order |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 1 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 2 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 111 | 3 |
| 111 | 3 |

Below is the code I have tried on my Original_data:

```
WITH phases AS (
  SELECT 'Found' AS phase, 1 AS phase_order UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Round 1', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Round 2', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Check', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Check Done', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wanted', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Captured', 9
), 
max_phase_id AS (
SELECT id, MAX(phase_order) AS max_phase
FROM orginal_data
GROUP BY id
)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * from max_phase_id
cross join phases
where phases.phase_order <= max_phase_id.max_phase) t
RIGHT JOIN  orginal_data
ON  orginal_data.id = t.id and t.phase = orginal_data.phase
order by phase_order
```

Another Example:

Original Data:

| ID | Phase | Phase Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Found | 1 |
| 14 | Round 1 | 2 |
| 14 | Round 2 | 3 |
| 14 | Check | 4 |
| 14 | Check | 4 |
| 14 | Check Done | 6 |
| 14 | Check Done | 6 |
| 14 | Wanted | 7 |

What Final output should be:

| ID | Phase | Phase Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Found | 1 |
| 14 | Found | 1 |
| 14 | Round 1 | 2 |
| 14 | Round 1 | 2 |
| 14 | Round 2 | 3 |
| 14 | Round 2 | 3 |
| 14 | Check | 4 |
| 14 | Check | 4 |
| 14 | Check Done | 6 |
| 14 | Check Done | 6 |
| 14 | Wanted | 7 |

Comment: So, for each row in the original_data, you want to select duplicated rows, and if the row is not duplicated then create a duplicated one for it, is that correct?

Comment: @ahmed I want to add the phases before a certain phase if they are not already in the original data. So if you look at the phases CTE, you see the first phase is Found and the last phase is wanted. In the original data since there is one wanted then there needs to be at least 1 row of every phase before wanted. Another example, is we have two phases that are 'Check Done', so there needs to be 2 rows for each phase before 'Check Done'.

Comment: Is it always 1 or 2 rows for a phase in the original_data, or it could be for example 4, hence, all phases before should be at least 4 rows.

Comment: it could be X so it could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
WITH phases AS (
  SELECT 'Found' AS phase, 1 AS phase_order UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Round 1', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Round 2', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Check', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Check Done', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Wanted', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Captured', 9
),
phases_counts as
(
  select PH.phase as new_phase, PH.phase_order as new_phase_order, 
         OD.id, OD.phase, OD.phase_order,
         count(*) over (partition by OD.id, PH.phase_order, OD.phase_order) cnt,
         max(OD.phase_order) over (partition by OD.id) as last_phase_in_od
  from
  phases PH left join orginal_data OD
  on PH.phase_order <= OD.phase_order
),
max_joined_phase_count as
(
  select *,
    rank() over (partition by id, new_phase_order order by cnt desc, phase_order desc) dr
  from phases_counts
) 
select id, new_phase as phase, new_phase_order as phase_order 
from max_joined_phase_count
 where dr = 1 and new_phase_order <= last_phase_in_od
order by id, phase_order
```

The logic of this query is, for each `phase_order` within an `ID` get all of the `phase_order`s that are greater than it, this is done by doing a left-join between the table/ cte that holds all of the possible phases and the `orginal_data` table, the use of left join is to get the missing phases from the `orginal_data` table.

After that, get the count of each joined phase and use the `rank` function ordered by that count in descending order, this will give `rank = 1` for the joined phase with the max count.

Now, we could select rows where `rank = 1`, and the phase order from the phases table is less that the max phase order of the `orginal_data` table.

[See a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TZtA4zC5) for all of the provided data samples

Comment: This actually isnt what I am looking for. This code, works for a few example of IDsHowever, I dont care about the phases decreasing count or not. I care that there is at least one phase sequentially before a given phase. So, If a phase, is on phase_order 5, that means there should be a row for phase order 1, 2, 3, and 4. Now if in the original data there is two rows that have phase order 5, then there should be two rows for phase_order 1, two rows for phase order 2, two rows for phase order 3, and two rows for phase order 4. Since, those phase must happen in order to get to phase 5.

Comment: I am going to put another example for a different id in my question

Comment: Well, it became more clear now, I updated the answer according to this, kindly check all possible cases you may have and update me if it's ok, I'll add clarification to the answer once you tell me that it's OK

Comment: that is it, thank you for your help would love the clarification when you get a chance!